# How to interprete the outcome for quasi-binomial models

Tags: regression, logistic, quasi-likelihood

I am currently trying to understand the quasi-binomial model and have a rather basic question, which I seem not to be able to see an answer. The outcomes in binomial models are binary. So, 0 vs 1, car vs bike, red vs blue, or Madonna vs Cher. The outcomes for quasi-binomial models on the other hand can be continuous, e.g. proportions, hence outcomes can be any number out of the range [0,1].

Frankly, in binomial models, the regression is conducted on the log-odds of 0 vs 1 for example.

What exactly do I model in quasi-binomial regression?